# Error when converting big files in R (from SAS to RDS)

Tags: r, file, bigdata

I am working with R and I have some big SAS files (around 7,000,000KB) that I need to convert into RDS, but it gives me the following error:

```
Evaluation error:cannot allocate vector of size 11.7Mb
```

How can I handle this big file to convert it into RDS?

Thank you!

Comment: `options("expressions"=200000)` first command in your R console, before the actual code..might help

Comment: In Windows command prompt window: `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/bin/x64>Rgui.exe --max-ppsize 500000`
The above command will launch new Rgui window. 
In that Rgui console window, type
> `options("expressions" = 200000)`